# Node.JS/Express - Get company products using URL params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I'm trying to retrieve products from a specific company in my application using RESTful API.

The GET method that I'm trying to use is something like this:

`http://localhost:3333/company/:company_id/products`

So I tried this approach:

```js
const routes = Router();

const company = `/company/:company_id`;
routes.use(`${company}/products`, productsRouter);

export default routes;
```

And then, inside the product router, I added this:

```js
const productsRouter = Router();
const productsController = new ProductsController();

productsRouter.get('/', productsController.index);

export default productsRouter;
```

If I try to access the route through the browser or Insomnia it finds the route correctly, but I can't get the `:company_id` parameter from the first route.
When I try to get it, but both `request.params` and `request.query` return nothing:

```js
public async index(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const { company_id } = request.params;
    const listProducts = container.resolve(ListProductsService);
    const products = await listProducts.execute(company_id);
    return response.json(products);
  }
```

Any thoughts on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`mergeParams`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router) option of Router.

> **`mergeParams`**
>
> Preserve the `req.params` values from the parent router. If the parent
> and the child have conflicting param names, the child’s value take
> precedence.
>
> *default value*: **false**

```
const productsRouter = Router({mergeParams: true});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you, Gabriele!